# Order a grouped list by the number of items in group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have grouped a list of documents based on a persons name.

I would like to have the name of the person with the most items at the top.

I.e

```
Paul  (5)
Steve (3)
Aaron (1)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Should i assume this can't be done?

Answer (score 0):

This CSR sort the groups by item-count:

```
Type.registerNamespace('SPOODOO')
SPOODOO.Demos = SPOODOO.Demos || {};
SPOODOO.Demos.Templates = SPOODOO.Demos.Templates || {}
SPOODOO.Demos.Functions = SPOODOO.Demos.Functions || {}

SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.Func1 = function (context) {
    ctx.ListData.Row.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt(b['Title.COUNT.group']) - parseInt(a['Title.COUNT.group']);
    });
}

SPOODOO.Demos.OnPreRender = SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.Func1;

SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField = function () {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(SPOODOO.Demos)
}

SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.MdsRegisterField = function () {
    var thisUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "Style Library/CSR/SortGroupsByCount.js";
    SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField();
    RegisterModuleInit(thisUrl, SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField)
}

if (typeof _spPageContextInfo != "undefined" && _spPageContextInfo != null) {
    SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.MdsRegisterField()
} else {
    SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField()
}
```

You might have have to change the thisUrl-variable to the acctual location of the CSR in your enviroment.